# How can I download Doxygen for C++ via NodeJS (i.e., via 'npm install')?

Tags: node.js, npm, doxygen

[Doxygen official download webpage](http://www.doxygen.nl/download.html) states this:

```
git clone https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen.git
```

What should I add in the `dependencies` section in my `package.json` file in order to download Doxygen via `npm install`?

Comment: Do you want to download the code or do you want to have executables. In the later case you will not find them at the place you indicate but installation packages are mentioned a little bit later on on the same page. I don't know how npm works, but I also have not heard that doxygen can be downloaded in this way.

Comment: @albert: I want to have an executable. Thanks.